# Kali Linux Can't Find Any Computer On Network

Tags: linux, networking, nmap, kali-linux

I'm trying nmap and arp. When i'm execute "arp -a" only shows

```
myhome.mynet ([my_ip]) at [MAC_ADDRESS] [ether] on wlan0
```

And when i'm trying to nmap [my_ip] it shows

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-04-03 00:23 EEST
Nmap scan report for xox.mynet (192.168.1.132)
Host is up (0.0000040s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on xox.mynet (192.168.1.132) are closed.
```

So, "xox" is my username and my question is, what is mynet and myhome? How can i change these for connect my local network and see other computers in lan? I can't find any help on internet.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a VM? Be sure to use Bridged vs NAT for your network settings.

Comment: No, my original OS is Kali Linux. There isn't any windows or VM.

Comment: Try what Rabin suggested: nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run nmap on all the subnet with the command

```
nmap 192.168.1.1-254
```

but you should probpobly start with the [manual](http://nmap.org/book/man.html) for nmap, or you can use Zenmap which is a GUI for nmap.

Comment: Thanks for answering Rabin, that worked. But the other question is, i'm trying to find like windows cmd "arp -a" command. When my default OS is windows, and i ran Kali in VM, it worked. But this time doesn't work.

Comment: i don't understand your question. you have the arp command on Linux as well. what are you trying to accomplish ?