# arp -a command not working doesn't list devices

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux, linux-terminal

First off, this is not a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/737016/kali-linux-cant-find-any-computer-on-network) question because it wasn't answered properly. My question is this:

When I type into terminal (Kali Linux):

`arp -a`

And I know that there are 7 devices connected to the network, I get this:

`Wireless_Broadband_Router.home (192.168.1.1) at f8:e4:fb:a1:a9:c8 [ether] on wlan0`

Only the router shows up! where's everything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic ARP mappings expire automatically after a couple minutes. You'll only have dynamic ARP mappings for devices your machine has sent unicast packets to recently. Do a ping-scan of your subnet (or maybe just ping the subnet-broadcast address or the all-hosts multicast address) and then rerun `arp -a`.

Also note that I believe the `arp` command has been deprecated on modern Linux. The replacement is the `ip` command, such as `ip neighbor show` or abbreviated `ip n show`.

Comment: how should I go about doing a ping-scan?

Comment: @Nitroman Lots of tools can do ping scans, but a popular one is `nmap`, e.g. `nmap -sn 192.168.1/24`

Comment: when I run `ip n show` I get this: `192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 lladdr f8:e4:fb:a1:a9:c8 REACHABLE` ONLY THE ROUTER!!!!

Comment: none of the other computers on the network show up.

Comment: @Nitroman Did you do anything that would have populated the list first? Like the ping scan I talked about? Can you connect to the other devices on your subnet?

Comment: no I didn't, should I?

Comment: @Nitroman Well, you're not going to see other machines in your arp cache unless your machine has needed to talk to them (via IPv4) within the last two minutes.

Comment: so I ran this command that I found online to do a  ping sweep:      `for i in {1...254}; do ping -c 1 -W 1 192.168.1.$i | grep 'from'; done`

Comment: AND IT WORKS!!!!!